# iOS - System Alert Location use in Background

Tags: ios, background, permissions, location

Sometimes I get an alert message, reminding me that my App is using the location service in the background.

If I read the [Official Documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033), in the `Give apps permission to use your Location` section.

> Other apps will ask for access to your location even when the app isn't in use. When you allow an app to always use your location, iOS will remind you which apps are able to use your location after an app uses your location in the background.

We can clearly admit that this alert will only be displayed when your App is using your location in the background.

So why am I asking this question ? Because this alert message just appeared when I woke up my phone, with no Apps in Background (all Apps were swiped up from the double tap Home button).

Does `Background` has other definition or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: As far as I know, your app can be woken up (launched implicitly) by the system depending on the background modes it supports. Even if you manually kill it in memory, it still can be triggered in background if there is an incoming data for it to process.

Comment: I guess it answers my question. Write an answer if you want to be accepted. Thank you btw

Comment: I wrote more detailed version as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can be woken up (launched implicitly) by the system depending on the background modes it supports.

[image]

Even if you manually kill it in memory by swiping up, it still can be triggered in background if there is an incoming data for it to process (such as **silent notification** with payload).